# Groovy - How to overload '+=' operator in a Map with compile static?

Tags: groovy, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

In Groovy, I can overload operator '+' plus as follow:

```
class MutableInt {
  int val

  MutableInt(int val) { this.val = val }

  MutableInt plus(int val) {                     
    return new MutableInt(this.val += val)
  }
}
```

The above class works fine for the following test cases:

```
def m1 = new MutableInt(1);
assert (m1 + 1).val == 2;
```

However, if I need to use it together with `Map` like this and compile it with static

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
void compileItWithStatic() {
  Map<Long, MutableInt> mutMap = [:].withDefault{ new MutableInt(0) }
  assert (mutMap[1L] += 20).val == 20;
}
compileItWithStatic()
```

I got the following error:

```
*Script1.groovy: 17: [Static type checking] - 
 Cannot call <K,V> java.util.Map <java.lang.Long, MutableInt>#putAt(java.lang.Long, MutableInt) with arguments [long, int]*
```

How can I override the '+=' operator and compile it with static without error?

**EDIT:**

If I am doing like this without compile static it works fine:

```
def m1 = new MutableInt(1);
assert (m1 += 1).val == 2  // <----- caution: '+=' not '+' as in previous case
```

However, if it was inside the method like this:

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
void compileItWithStatic_2() {
  def m1 = new MutableInt(1);
  assert (m1 += 1).val == 2
}
```

The error will be:

```
Script1.groovy: -1: Access to java.lang.Object#val is forbidden @ line -1, column -1.
1 error
```

*P.S. It won't work with static compilation not with dynamic compilation.*

Answer (score 1):

The assignment part is throwing the error. A simple `+` works:

```
class MutableInt {
  int val

  MutableInt(int val) { this.val = val }

  MutableInt plus(int val) {                     
    return new MutableInt(this.val += val)
  }
}

def m1 = new MutableInt(1);
assert (m1 + 1).val == 2;


@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
def compileItWithStatic() {
  Map<Long, MutableInt> mutMap = [:].withDefault{ new MutableInt(0) }
  mutMap[1L] + 20
  mutMap
}

assert compileItWithStatic()[1L].val == 20
```

Groovy is parsing `mutMap[1L] += 20` as `mutMap.putAt(1L, 20)`. This looks like a bug to me. This works: `mutMap[1L] = mutMap[1L] + 20`, albeit more verbose.

---

**Edit:** the second error seems related to the result of the expression `(m1 + 1)` being parsed as `Object`. This should work:

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
void compileItWithStatic_2() {
  def m1 = new MutableInt(1) + 1;
  assert m1.val == 2
}
```

Comment: I put 'void' to demonstrate the compile static. By removing '=' it will go back to the same implementation. I have modified the question code a bit (adding assertion).

Comment: Hmm.. Do I also need to override putAt method to support '+=' with `Map`?

Comment: No, the `putAt` method is being called on the `map` object, and not on `MutableInt`. I've updated my answer to show the map value being updated

Comment: Well, it is just making everything verbose.. ~.~
but it didn't really answer on how I can override `+=` operator.

Comment: There is no way to override the `+=` operator. It is a simple `+` operator.

Comment: Though probably the `+=` behaviors differently when it comes to maps

Comment: I have to disagree if there is no way to override the `+=` operator. Now, how can groovy implement the `Date` class like this:
     @groovy.transform.CompileStatic
     void compileitWithStatic() {
        def d = new Date();
        d += 1; //<--- this one "+="
        println d;
     }
​     compileitWithStatic()​;​

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83785/discussion-between-will-p-and-exodream).